# React: setState called twice even after spreading previous state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-state

So, i have faced similar issues in the past, but could always figure out where i am missing to spread or assign a new object, while trying to update previous state. But i can't seem to figure out what i am doing wrong this time.

I have a state, in a functional component, that looks like this:

```
formData = {name: '', features: []}
```

And trying to update the `features` array with the following snippet:

```
function handleUpdate(featureUID) {
 console.log('Called parent')     

 setFormData(prev => {
   const spread = Object.assign({}, prev)
   let features = [...spread.features]
   if (features.includes(featureUID)) {
     features = features.filter(x => x !== featureUID)
   } else {
     features = [...features, featureUID]
   }
   console.log('Features:', features)
   spread.features = [...features]

   return spread
 })
}
```

So as you can see, i am initially *assigning* a shallow-copied version of `prev` to `spread` and further down, i also create a shallow copy of the `features` array.

But seems like after the first invocation of this method, on all consequent calls triggers the *setState* twice.

What am i missing here?

**Edit 1**

Forgot to mention the function that holds the `setFormData` aka *setState* is only being called once, confirmed via console logging. The way i am calling it:

```
{otherList?.map(single => <Button key={single.uid} onClick={() => handleUpdate(single.uid)}/>)}
```

**Edit 2**

I am aware of the fact that `StrictMode` causes the *twice calling* of setState. But i also know why it's that way. So not willing to remove `StrictMode`

**Edit 3**

Tried this and seems to work:

```
setFormData(prev => ({
  ...prev,
  features: prev.features.includes(featureUID)
    ? prev.features.filter(x => x !== featureUID)
    : [...prev.features, featureUID]
}))
```

But what i don't understand is, Why ? What did i miss in my first approach?

Comment: Show how you call `setFormData` please

Comment: @Konrad Updated, please check.

Comment: Can you knock up a working snippet, it's a bit unclear what you mean `setState` called twice, your current setState your showing is on a onClick is will be called how ever many times you click, and strict mode will not make a difference there.

Comment: @Keith It's not the issue with the onclick, as that's firing only once. I will try to sum up a working sample